# How to mock dependency in service class from Junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to write the test cases of one of my service method. I am packing error like cannot invoke

`Cannot invoke "com.company.app.models.Product.getId()"` because "product" is null

This is my service class

```
@Service
@Log4j2
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({ @Autowired, @Lazy }))
public class SomeService {

  private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
  private final AccountMapper accountMapper;
  private final ProductService productService;
 

  public Account doSomeOperation(AccountRequest accountRequest) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Product product = productService.findByName(accountRequest.getProductName());
    Account account = (accountRequest.getId() != null) ? accountRepository.findById(accountRequest.getId())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Account Not found with id - " + accountRequest.getId()))
        : new Account();

    accountMapper.merge(accountRequest, account);
    account.setProductId(product.getId());
    return accountRepository.save(account);
  }
```

This is my service class

```
@WebMvcTest(MigrationService.class)


class MigrationServiceTest {


    @Mock
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Mock
    private ProductService productService;

    @Mock
    private AccountMapper mapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeService someService;

    
 @Test
 void testDoSomeOperation() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    // Arrange
    AccountRequest accountRequest = new AccountRequest();
    accountRequest.setProductName(“myProduct”);
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setId(1L);
    when(accountRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(new Account()));
    when(accountRepository.save(any(Account.class))).thenReturn(new Account());

    // Act
    Account migratedAccount = migrationService.migrateAccount(accountRequest);

    // Assert
    assertNotNull(migratedAccount);
    assertEquals(product.getId(), migratedAccount.getProductId());
    // Add more assertions as needed
}


}
```

Now I have checked the myProduct in database table which is available in database. But In this life I am not getting the value is null Product product = productService.findByName(accountRequest.getProductName());

What is I am missing ?

Comment: Put a debug point in your service class and check the value of `accountRepository`,  you need to ensure if mocked object is getting injected or not

Comment: yes, `accountRepository` is accesable once code flow from test class to sevice. How to make sure  mocked object is getting injected or not, and if not what changes shall i do in code. @NawnitSen

Comment: Please have a look at detailed answer, issue is something else here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing mocked instance of `productService` but you aren't mocking method `findByName`. And hence when this method is called on mocked instance you are getting null as a return value. Add below line to mock the method on product service.

`when(productService.findByName(any())).thenReturn(new Product());`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try and back to here.  Also in similar way I need to write this line `accountRepository.save(account);` alos ?

Comment: The idea of mocking a method is to actually predefine its behaviour, usually You would mock the method which requires extra setup to run , for example repository calls are Database calls which in your case you haven't done for the test case. So you mock it.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I understood. I am getting lots of services the similar issue, No i guess I will fix.